# Use Javascript to extract thumbnail from JPEG?

Tags: javascript, jpeg, autoload

Lots of cameras are now putting thumbnails into their JPEGs and RAWs images.
I'd like to be able to autoload some images and then display only the thumbnail, or better yet autoload only the thumbnail portion for speed.

Is there a way to do this in Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "autoload"? Also, do you want to do this in a browser, or as a stand-alone program/process? (JavaScript != browser, so I'm asking the question; I'd expect you'd mention it if you were using NodeJS or Adobe AIR or...)

Comment: By autoload I mean loading the thumbnails before the page is rendered. This would be in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

You've said you want to do this in the browser, so when you say:

> ...or better yet autoload only the thumbnail portion for speed.

You're not going to get a speed benefit from doing this client-side, because the entire image must first be downloaded before you can make a thumbnail for it.

You *can* create thumbnails for retrieved images, just by creating an `img` element and settings its `width` and `height` to something smaller; the default thing browsers will do is scale the image down (not necessarily in a pretty way).

Example:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "your image url here";
img.style.width = "32px";       // Change as appropriate
img.style.height = "32px";      // Change as appropriate
document.body.appendChild(img); // Or append to some other container element
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/orosu5)

There I've assumed it's apprpropriate to *force* the image to be a certain width and height (frequently with thumbnails, it's useful if they're all the same size, although the above will mess with aspect ratios).

If you want to resize by a percentage (say, 25%), you can do that but it's more complicated: You have to create the image, load it off-screen (there are various ways to do this), wait for the load to complete, and then do the calculation.

---

If you're running a server, you're probably better off finding something that can pre-process the images and create thumbnails for you. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), for instance, can help with that server-side.

Comment: Well, I'm a C coder mainly, so when I say fetch only the thumbnail that's inside a JPEG for speed, what I mean is reading the JPEG header and skipping ahead in the file as it's being read from a socket, to access *only* the preexisting thumbnail. (Most people do not know that these are produced by cameras, I know.) This approach could cut down on network traffic, especially with large JPEGs. But I guess that kind of thing is too intense for Javascript.

Comment: @user: It's not a C vs. JavaScript thing, it's the level of protocol exposed to the environment by the browser. I'm not aware of any browser that exposes range unit control (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.12) at the scripting level. You'd need that if you wanted to read the JPEG header and extract the EXIF thumbnail info without downloading the entire image. Again, best handled server-side.